# How to post with generated client in micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I'm getting an error when posting to a simple hello controller in micronaut. The client seems to be posting as application/json but the controller expects text/plain. How do I fix the client to post as text/plain?

HelloController.java

```
@Post(value = "/helloBody/{name}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Single<String> helloBody(@NotBlank String name, @NotBlank @Body String text) {
    return Single.just(name + "sent: " + text);
}
```

HelloClient.java

```
@Post(value = "/helloBody/{name}")
Single<String> helloBody(@NotBlank String name, @NotBlank String body);
```

HelloControllerTest.java

```
@Test
void testPost() {
    String body = client.helloBody("John", "message").blockingGet();
    assertThat(body).isEqualTo("John sent: message");
}
```

Error

```
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Content Type [application/json] not allowed. Allowed types: [text/plain]
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1799)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1739)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
...
```

Comment: Does changing `consumes =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` do anything? Not 100% familiar with Spring myself.

Comment: That would be a change in the controller. What I need is a change in the client to send the request as text/plain.

Comment: Maybe try adding parameter `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to the client @Post? Not sure if it compiles but it's worth a shot

Comment: Oops, `produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`

Comment: @Avi it's Micronaut, not Spring. But of course very similar.

Comment: @saw303 :( Didn't see that, my bad. Fortunately there are other people more familiar with Micronaut than myself who can provide good answers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this by tell the client to send `text/plain` as the backend expects.

```java
@Post(value = "/helloBody/{name}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
Single<String> helloBody(@NotBlank String name, @NotBlank String body);
```

The idea in Micronaut is to make *web operations* shareable between a controller and a client.

Let's think of a interface called `HelloOperations`. This is your web interface that can be shared between the client and server.

```java
@Validated
public interface HelloOperations {

  @Post(value = "/helloBody/{name}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  Single<String> helloBody(@NotBlank String name, @NotBlank @Body String text);
}
```

Now you start implementing the contract in the backend with a controller implementation such as

```java
@Controller
public class HelloController implements HelloOperations {

   @Override
   public Single<String> helloBody(String name, String text)  {

     // do something in here...
   }
}
```

after that you continue on the client side.

```java
@Client
public interface HelloWorldClient extends HelloOperations {

   @Override
   Single<String> helloBody(String name, String text);
}
```

Et voilà. You successfully connected them.

Further explanations can be found in the Micronaut documentation at https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientAnnotation

Comment: Ok I have it fixed. I had to make your change and add produces to the controller and client. `@Post(value = "/helloBody/{name}", consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`

Comment: see my complete example how you can achieve a nice client/server implementation with Micronaut

Comment: This is very nice. Thanks for the help!